# Expression cannot be a statement is a error that I have been receiving for this method here :

Tags: apex

```
public static String getTaxCodeTriggerByIndex(Tax_Code__c taxCodes) {
    for (Tax_Code__c taxCode : taxCodes) {
          taxCode.Tax_Code__c + 
          taxCode.Tax_Code_Prefix__c +
          taxCode.Tax_Code_Letter__c +
          taxCode.Tax_Code_Number__c; 
        }
    
    return getTaxCodeTriggerByIndex();
}
```

Any suggestions and explanations would be great thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome! Could you expand on what your Apex method is trying to achieve? I notice that you are taking a single `Tax_Code__c` but you have named it `taxCodes`. Did you mean to use a `List`?

Comment: @fred Thank you and the Apex method is essentially to add all the objects selected into a value for a trigger. I was considering to use a list but I wasnt sure if it was best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not assigning the value to a variable, that's why.

You probably want to assign the concatenation of the prefix, letter and number to the code field, right?

```
taxCode.Tax_Code__c = // notice the EQUAL sign
taxCode.Tax_Code_Prefix__c +
taxCode.Tax_Code_Letter__c +
taxCode.Tax_Code_Number__c;
```

Or even better, for more readability:

```
String taxCode = 
  taxCode.Tax_Code_Prefix__c +
  taxCode.Tax_Code_Letter__c +
  taxCode.Tax_Code_Number__c; 

taxCode.Tax_Code__c = taxCode;
```

Comment: Yes I did. Ok I see what you mean, thank you

Comment: @AngelaS and if you're just combining fields together for `Tax_Code__c`, you should consider making it a formula field instead (writing code means you need to also test/maintain that code)